# Access this from another class React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am currently factoring my code so as not to repeat the same lines x times, so I created a Functions.js file which I use to call functions from other classes. The problem is, that I cannot execute the function while keeping the properties of this to carry out setState, redirects etc. Here is an example, it will be more telling:

Class in functions.js :

```
export class KoHttpRequest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.postRequest = this.postRequest.bind(this);
  }

  postRequest = async(url, json, accessToken) => {
    this.setState({loaded: false, validatingAction: false});
    fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '.concat(accessToken)
                },
                body: json
            }).then((response) => {
              if (response.ok === true) {
                this.fetchData().then(() => {
                  this.setState({loaded: true}, () => {
                    this.userIsValidatingAnAction();
                    setTimeout(() => {this.setState({validatingAction: false})}, 1000);
                  });
                })
              } else {
                let error = JSON.stringify(response.headers.map);
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Accueil', {failedAction: true, errorReason: error.split('"error-reason":').pop().split('}},')[0].concat(' URL : '.concat(response.url))});
              }
            })
       .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
       });
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And in the file where I want to call it :

```
import { KoHttpRequest } from '../Components&Functions/Koust.js';


createNewInvoice = () => {
     new KoHttpRequest().postRequest('https://koupp.com/apex/rest/mobile/facture', JSON.stringify({
           type:'C',
           numero:this.state.invoiceNumber,
           date_liv:this.state.pickedDate,
           provider_id:this.state.selectedProvider
         }), this.state.accessToken);
   };
```

So, to explain clearly, in the class, the .then() and .error() are same for all request I do in my app, that's why I need the code here and not in the class that is calling it.
Unfortunely, I don't understand how I can tell the function that the 'this' referenced to use is in the other component. Cause actually the function is using themselve props..

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid repeating to setState logic or the api request logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just trying to access the setState of class that is calling it.
In Functions.js, when it's using setState, I want it set the state of the other class actually

EDIT :

I think I found a solution using a callback.

```
createNewInvoice = () => {
     this.setState({loaded: false, validatingAction: false}, () => {
       new KoHttpRequest().koPostRequest('https://koupp.com/apex/rest/mobile/facture', JSON.stringify({
             type:'C',
             numero:this.state.invoiceNumber,
             date_liv:this.state.pickedDate,
             provider_id:this.state.selectedProvider
           }), this.state.accessToken, this.props, function(result) {
             if (result.status === 200) {
               this.fetchData().then(() => {
                 this.setState({loaded: true}, () => {
                   this.userIsValidatingAnAction();
                   setTimeout(() => {this.setState({validatingAction: false})}, 1000);
                 });
               })
             }
           });
     });
   };
```

But now, that's the callback function that can't access "this".

EDIT_2:

Find it. Just need to replace function() {..} by () => {..}

Thanks!